# Can sparse set cover problem be solved or approximated more efficiently comparing to its non-sparse counter part?

Tags: solver, software, set-covering

I am an electrical engineer who is currently working with some bench table placement problem, and suddenly my problem look pretty much like the set cover problem [here](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Set_covering_problem). After that, some of my colleague told me that most problem in engineering is quite sparse and this should be exploited.

Therefore, my question is:

Can sparse set cover problem be solved or approximated more efficiently comparing to its non-sparse counter part ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 4):

For a given set of dimensions, a sparse model is likely to be faster to solve than a dense one simply because fewer nonzero coefficients mean less arithmetic per iteration of whatever algorithm you are using. However, there is no guarantee that a specific sparse instance will solve faster than a specific dense instance of the same dimension.

As for exploiting sparsity, if you are using an integer programming model and an IP solver, there is a good chance that the IP solver internally exploits sparsity (for instance, by using matrix factorization techniques that benefit from sparsity).

Comment: Thank you ! Such a great insight. Could you please be nore specific on what kind of matrix factorisation technique for sparse set cover problem ?

Comment: What I had in mind was not specific to set covering problems. For a general linear or mixed integer linear programming problem, you have a linear constraint set $Ax=b$ which, for a given basis, is partitioned into a basic part ($Bx_B=b,$ with $B$ nonsingular) and a nonbasic part ($Nx_N = 0,$ with $x_N = 0.$ In textbooks (and old solver codes) you would solve $Bx_B = b$ by inverting $B.$ Current practice does not invert $B$ but rather factors it, perhaps using an LU decomposition, perhaps SVD or some other decomposition. (I'm being vague because I'm not a solver author.)